# Trying to Create a game where the will be a Regular User and an Admin, in C++ but Stucked when I have to get the inheritance correct. Who to Inherit

Tags: c++, inheritance

In C++ I am trying the subject of OOP in the line of creating a console-based game with a regular user and the admin. Where admin can add new users, add game rules, and more. While the user can only play the game without having access to the ability of the admin.

Now I am trying to get a way to have the user to inherit from the admin but the user should not get the privilege of all the admin functions like changing password add game rules and so forth.

````
class admin{
string name 
string password
changePAssword();
changeRules();
addNewGames();

};
class user: public admin{
string name 
string password

void play();
void login();
void quit();
} ```


//The user does not have to be able to function as an admin and vice-versa.
 For example, in MCQ game I have a question and answer choices the user can put their choice but cannot change the choices and questions only the admin has such rights.
````

Comment: Shouldn't `admin` derive from `user`, rather than the other way round?

Comment: Thanks on that I am trying to make sure like I can change the rules using similar things the user need to play the game but ensuring I can change them not Him example in MCQ i have question and answer choices the user can put their choice but cannot change the choices and questions.

Comment: Inheritance means "Every X is a Y".  Your code says that "Every `user` is an admin".  It should be the other way around: "Every `admin` is a `user`, so `admin` should inherit from `user`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it seems to me is that admin should inherit from user as admin has more abilities. Your code should look like this:

```
class user{
string name 
string password

void play();
void login();
void quit();
}
class admin: public user{
changePAssword();
changeRules();
addNewGames();

};
```

You don't need to restate name and password as they are inherited from user.

Comment: How would I be able to change the password and username and password and not allowing the user to do so?

Comment: Thanks on that I am trying to make sure like I can change the rules using similar things the user need to play the game but ensuring I can change them not Him example in MCQ i have question and answer choices the user can put their choice but cannot change the choices and questions.

Comment: In that case, you might want to use different classes without inheritance.

Comment: Or make a separate `credentials` class, and all the methods for that take an `admin`.

Comment: @MooingDuck or the line of credentials class should be only holding the user's credentials and should inherit its methods from admin? Is this what you are referring too?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ApAdllI0vHlvWgoDWMAEJQgmwwTzpLY_/view?usp=sharing ) Here is the link to the UML diagram of this project for little guidance

Comment: @TikaMBELA the `credentials` class should not inherit from anything, it should be 100% separate.  and its `changePassword` member should take an `admin&` parameter, to ensure that only the admin can change the password.  Since `user` does not inherit from `admin`, a `user` would be unable to call the method at all.